# I declare [declarations] be a synonym of [declaration]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

## [Link to vote on this tag synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/declaration/synonyms)

[declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/declarations) only has 41 tagged questions but [declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/declaration) has 1547 tagged questions.

Currently [declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/declarations) has no tag wiki but [declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/declaration) does.

Comment: [support]? You should tag this as [discussion]

Comment: I saw other synonym requests tagged as support. I wasn't sure what the right tag was. I've changed it now.

Comment: Really, that's strange. The tag wiki should tell people: *A request for assistance with one of the site's features.* Making synonyms? I totally need help from the great Stack Overflow!

Comment: @Zizouz212: Actually, in this case you should [read the tag-wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonym-request/info) for [meta-tag:synonym-request], not discussion/support. Both are good here.

Comment: I feel that retagging those 41 questions is easier.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Such a moderator assistance is for example when tags should be merged and not just synonymized. Merging tags is a destructive action and can only be done by moderators. (Actually I don't know whether it's still destructive since StackOverflow strives to be soft delete only, but some time ago it was an issue when something was merged and later discovered that it shouldn't have been merged)

Comment: I'm not even sure what is tag satire and what is serious at this point.

Comment: Does the *content* of the questions in [tag:declarations] match the tag wiki for [tag:declaration]? Or are there types of different content that might need to be retagged with something else?

Comment: Yes, I've been scanning the declarations questions and they all appear to be related to a formal type declaration.

Comment: @Braiam retagging without creating the synonym would allow the issue to reoccur.

Comment: @b4hand nope, no tags shall be created which differ by an s at the end. That was done to stop with the madness of double tagging for things that had plurals. Try it ;).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Obviously, I'm in favor of this proposal since I initially asked it. My reasoning is that if you look at the questions it seems like the [declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/declarations) are all just plural accidentally without checking the existence of the singular version first. The [declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/declarations) questions sometimes ask about a single declaration and similarly the [declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/declaration) questions often ask about multiple declarations.

I don't see any utility in splitting these tags. They are already rather niche with less than two thousand questions in total between the two of them with the bulk already belonging to the singular version.

Finally since [declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/declarations) has no wiki, there is really no information loss in combining the two.

Comment: You missed that both these tags have existed for nearly 7 years?  That kinda shoots down the "failure to check the existence of the singular version".

Comment: I don't think anyone happened to intentionally choose plural over singular or vice versa. My guess is that at one point they both got created and then whatever people happened to type first they used without checking for an alternate spelling. This is a good reason to consider them synonyms.

Answer (score 7):

There are now no questions tagged [declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/declarations).  I voted for the synonymization, but for a mere 40-odd questions, retagging is effective and doable.  For 400 questions, creating a synonym should be easier.

Comment: It's up to 3. It will probably get synonymed shortly.

Answer (score -1):

I feel like [declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/declarations) should be the master, even though it currently isn't used as much, and this is why:

[declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/declarations) covers every question involving any number of declarations.  If you can have a problem with a single declaration, it can also occur when you have more than one.

[declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/declaration) might not cover issues that only arise when multiple declarations are involved, such as agreement between multiple declarations, incompatible declaration, circular dependencies between declarations, etc.

Comment: The [tag:declaration] already had questions related to multiple declarations, and I think the convention is for tags to be singular.

Comment: @b4hand: Some are, some aren't: [tag:arrays], [tag:arguments], [tag:methods], [tag:smart-pointers], [tag:pointers], [tag:templates], [tag:debug-symbols], [tag:huge-pages], [tag:collections], [tag:design-patterns], [tag:polynomials], and those are just the ones currently on the front page

Comment: @BenVoigt ...I feel like [tag:arguments] is gonna cause a flame war at some point.

Comment: "Declaration" can refer to the act, the concept or the syntactical element. "Declarations" would be awkward for anything but the latter. All flavors of the same thing, and deserving of one tag, but not all such questions will focus on the syntactical element. Cases involving multiple declarations are *multiple declaration* cases, a subset of *declaration*... I prefer the singular. It's not a big deal and the wiki's already there.